# Defining atom function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm new with common-lisp and my stuck with this easy problem.
I need to define a function that return true if the input is an atom

So, if in enter in the command line atom 'a returns T, but my code not

Variable x has to be quoted or the result will be false.

(defun check (x)

if(atom 'x)

T)

Answer (score 1):

There already is a function that does that.  It is called `atom`:

```
(atom 1)
=> T

(atom '(1))
=> NIL
```

This is thus a rather pointless exercise.  If you absolutely must, you could wrap it in another function call:

```
(defun pointless-exercise (x)
  (atom x))

(pointless-exercise 1)
=> T

(pointless-exercise '(1))
=> NIL
```

Note that you absolutely must not quote that `x` in your function:

```
(defun failed-exercise (x)
  (atom 'x))

-> WARNING: parameter x is unused

(failed-exercise 1)
=> T

(failed-exercise '(1))
=> T ; oops
```

That is because `'x` means that the symbol `x` stands for itself and is not evaluated as a variable name, and a symbol is always an atom.

Comment: Yes, i know how atom works, but the function i am writing has to reply T also for check a, but a is a string and if is not quoted is not an atom.

Comment: In the console if i type atom 1 returns true if i type (atom a) it doesn' t work, if i type atom 'a returns true. So my function has to return T for (check a) but i don't know how to do it

Comment: If you type `(atom a)` then `a` is evaluated as a variable.  If it is unbound, it gives an error.  If you want `atom` to return `T` for a symbol, you have to pass the symbol to it, e. g. `(atom 'a)`.  If you wrap `atom` in your `check`, you still have to pass a symbol, e. g. `(check 'a)`.

Comment: So i have to pass 'a in the command line, i thought i could pass only a and then transform it into a symbol. By the way, thank you.

Comment: @Aonna A character string is an atom in Common Lisp. A "quoted string" isn't a string at all, but a two-element list like `(quote "abc")`, whose first element is the symbol `quote` and whose second element is a string. The `atom` function correctly reports `nil` for such a thing. The trick is that we have to quote it: `(atom '(quote "abc"))` which is the same as `(atom ''"abc")`.

Answer (score 1):

[This is an extended comment which is too long for one.]

Based on your comments either you are confused or your function cannot be written in Common Lisp.

Here's why:

- you are writing a function, and so your function will obey the standard evaluation rules of the language for function applications;
- you require your function, `check` to return `t` in a form `(check a)` where `a` is not previously known.

These two conditions can not be met.  They can't be met because the evaluation rules for the language forbid it.  In a form like `(check a)` the rules are:

1. find out what sort of thing `check` refers to;
2. if it refers to a function, evaluate all its arguments in left-to-right order in the current environment;
3. retrieve the function binding of `check` from the current environment (this step can happen before, after, or during (2));
4. apply it to the results of (2).

See [3.1.2.1.2.3](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababc.htm) of the Hyperspec.

In your case this process fails at (2): `a` has no binding and so evaluation of `a` signals an error.

Given that you are being asked to write a function you must have misunderstood the question.

Further, it's unlikely that you were being asked merely to write a wrapper around `atom`: rather the chances are the question wanted you either to *reimplement* `atom` (hint: what is its definition?), or to implement some variant of `atom` which considers a different set of objects to be 'atomic' than `atom` does.  Which of those is true we can't tell from your question as it stands (v1).

Comment: I thought i could write in the command line (check a), a is passed to the function, quoted and trasformed in a string so i could decide whether is an atom or not. But i was replied that i can't do that so i should write (check 'a) in the command line. So a must be quoted